# Inheritance in generic winforms controls

Tags: winforms, generics

Is it possible to have winforms designer working for Control2 for the following scenario?

```
public class Control1 <T> : UserControl {}

public class Control2 <T> : Control1<T> {}
```

Comment: I am getting the following message:
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the following classes in the file: Control2. The base class Control1<T> could not be loaded.  Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

Comment: It is possible - you need to override the `Initialize` method and the constructor, altough i never done this for UserControls with generic parameters. Have a look at this [CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37830/Designing-Nested-Controls) and this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171820.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer cannot work with a generic type as it does not any idea which TYPE to put in for 'T'.  You will need to create a concrete class for this to work:

```
public class StringControl2 : Control2<string> {}
```